# kdb/q building NBBO from TAQ data

Tags: kdb

I have a table with bid/ask for for every stock/venue.  Something like:

```
taq:`time xasc ([] time:10:00:00+(100?1000);bid:30+(100?20)%30;ask:30.8+(100?20)%30;stock:100?`STOCK1`STOCK2;exhcnage:100?`NYSE`NASDAQ)
```

How can I get the best/bid offer from all exchanges as of a time (in one minute buckets) for every stock?

My initial thought is to build a table that has a row for every minute/exchange/stock and do a asof join on the taq data.  However, it sounds to me this is a brute force solution - since this is a solved problem, i figured i'd ask if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select max bid, min ask by stock,1+minute from 0!select by 1 xbar time.minute,stock,exchange from taq
```

This will give you the max bid, min ask across exchanges at the 1-minute interval in column `minute`.

The only tricky thing is the `select by 1 xbar time.minute`. When you do select by with no aggregation, it will just return the last row. So really what this means is `select last time, last bid, last ask .... by 1 xbar time.minute` etc.

So after we get the last values by minute and exchange, we just get the `min`/`max` across exchanges for that minute.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that